# Is oracle client necessary for making odbc connection

Tags: java, oracle, odbc

Is oracle 11g client necessary to be installed if I need oracle11gr odbc drivers to establish a connection for my some application deployment?

Application is written in `Java` and it needs to be connected via DSN with an Oracle database on some other server.

I'm confused in this fundamental concept!

Comment: I mean what if I only install oracle11gr odbc drivers instead of whole client? will it work?

Comment: application is written in Java and it needs to be connected via dsn with an oracle database on some other server. Now the machine on which I'm going to deploy the application needs oracle client to be installed for making odbc dsn to my server??

Comment: Please update the question instead of using comments to clarify the situation.

Comment: I need oracle odbc drivers without installing oracle 11g on my pc. Is it clear?